# Dynamics AX , items on wmslocation

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012

New to Dynamics AX,how to get all the item in particular wmslocation and what is the relation b/w  wmslocation and inventTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to create an on-hand counting journal for that WMS location.

There is no direct relation between these two tables. The item id from the inventtable can be used to connect to the inventtrans table. The inventtrans table has the itemid, transaction type (inventory transaction, transfer, item counting, etc) and the InventDimID. The InventDim table has a link to the particular dimension group you are looking for (wmslocationid).

So the SQL would look something like:

```
select distinct (itemid) from inventTrans where inventdimid in 
(select inventDimid from inventDim
where wmslocationid = 'WMSLocationID you care about here')
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do something similar (using site id). This worked really well.